What is it called when the inference is biased internally but accurate externally?
Let say you are to make some inference about something, say a population. Typically you would take a small sample of that population and then make some inference. How you analyze that sample basically drives how accurate your inference is about that population.
Now say you somehow managed to get information about the entire population. In this case, obviously you would be most accurate as you get to know information about the entire population.
So you use information about whole thing to predict the nature of the whole thing itself - which should be just trivial.
My above question may not look directly related to English but some other subject, but that is just an example. Basically, what I am trying to convey is that if you compare or infer on something internally, you will mostly get biased view, so your benchmark should be external. Another example may be, if we stand on an open field and look at the horizon, we may infer that the Earth is flat. But to make proper inference about the shape of the Earth, we need to go external, i.e. ride above the atmosphere and see that the Earth is indeed a sphere.
I wonder if there is any specific phrase or word or way to describing above situation?

How you analyze that sample basically drives how accurate your inference is about that population. Can you please be a bit more specific? It's the size of the sample that determines the statistical accuracy of the inference. What inference?

The accuracy of large samples follows the Law of Large Numbers.

This question is better asked on Mathematics.SE; the language is subject specific.

Please follow the rules for the tag to make this question more clear. I'm not even sure what aspect of the situation you're looking to capture (eg, the overkill of measuring the entire population, a word to replace "inference" since you know the exact number, something else?)

You draw an inference about a population from a sample statistic. You either take a measurement or state an observation about a population. Is that what you're looking for?

This is a question ostensibly about words in English, but really is more about the concepts (and terminology) in a domain specific area. You will probably get better luck on a stats specific site like [stats.SE] or [data science.SE]. But the two things you're asking about are named 'sample statistics' and 'population statistic'. In the case of a population statistic there's no inference at all, no prediction, no confidence interval. But it's still called a statistic

You need to work hard at improving the question. It really doesn't make any sense as asked. And "How you analyze that sample basically drives how accurate your inference is about that population." is not correct.

About the only concept words that make sense as asked are interpolate and extrapolate.

The title of this question is about (1) the distinction between being biased internally and accurate externally; most of the body of the question is about (2) the sample/population distinction; at the end there is (3) the example about the difference between observing the shape of the Earth from its surface and from a point higher up. It is not obvious how these three components of the question are related to each other.
